# Why is guanidine considered a strong base?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I've studied $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}(\ce{H2O}) = 15,$ and anything with a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ lower than should be an acid. Guanidine has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $13.8$ and is being called by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanidine) a strong base. Why is it so?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia), ammonia is a weak base. Then why is its $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ much higher than the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of guanidine?

Comment: Equivalent resonance in [amidine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidine) bases

Comment: It's pKa  of conjugated acid ($\ce{pK_{bH^+}}$) - it's protonated form is about as acidic as water.

Comment: due to the stability of carbocation formed after protanation

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(chemistry)#Strong_bases) notes that if a base (in water solution) has a conjugate acid whose $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ exceeds $13,$ it's a strong base.  The criterion is (apparently) based on complete or at least predominant dissociation up to $0.1$ molar.  Guanidine makes it, ergo a strong base.

Comment: We know that ammonia is a weak base than why is its pka much higher than Guanidine
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia

Comment: Conjugate acid pKa < 13.

Comment: But Wikipedia states pka of Guanidine<pka of ammonia

Comment: No.  The number for guanidine is for its conjugate acid while the number for ammonia is for NH3 itself, the conjugate acid for ammonia would be about pKa=5.  Conjugate acid pKa is what counts for identifying a strong base.  It's inconsistent nomenclature, yes that sucks.